# WordSearch: Fiction (Sci-fi Realism) that diverges from true history at a previous and defined point in time

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for the word/ term for a sub-genre of Fiction, that makes use of the actual real timeline as its backstory, but deviates at a specific point prior to the beginning of narration.

Example:

- Story set in 2000,
- in a world where aliens made contact in 1920,
- but everything up until 1920 conforms to our true history.
- (complicated further by sci-fi / disregard of some physics applied to events post 1920)

There is the term Alternate History Fiction, but that seems to require the example story to begin in 1920, and the sci-fi elements seem to make that an awkward fit.

There is the term Alternate Reality Fiction but that refers to multiple parallel universes.

Is there a term for the type of story described?

Comment: I'd call it alternate history. I'd never heard of the requirement that an alternate history story has to begin at any particular point in time. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: [Here](http://www.jessesword.com/sf/list/?subject=sf_criticism) you can find some definitions and examples of how the terms alternate history, alternate reality, etc. have been used.

Comment: I think you'll find that the whole mess of terms, alternate/alternative history/reality/universe/world are synonyms and loosely defined so you can use any one of them to mean whatever you want.

Comment: Your story begins either way in 1920. It might not be in the first paragraph, but alien making contact that year is part of your story. So you fulfill your own Alternate History Fiction prerequisite.

Comment: That's an extremely interesting observation, Helmar. The connotation feels off, though. @user191160 brings up dystopian science fiction. While not as clearly dystopian as 1984 and Farenheight 451, there is a strong theme of runaway technology and human avarice and hubris. It seems like the connotation of dystopian science fiction is a much better fit than that of alternate history, which I normally would associate with period pieces. Dystopian fiction often(always?) begins narration after the societal changes have occurred, which is an important distinction in this limited-info story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon what you have purported in the description, it seems like as though **dystopian** fits the best. Most prominent dystopian books, such as 1984 and Farenheight 451, retain human history, but project a contemporary fear or risk far into the future, and exaggerate it to serve as a warning for what could eventually become reality.

**Dystopia**: *An imagined place or state in which everything is unpleasant or bad, typically a totalitarian or environmentally degraded one.*

I don't think there is a specific term exclusively for books that are based in the future but retain the past as we know it. I think the genre for books with such a premise is completely respective to the book. The example you gave though seems to qualify as a **dystopian science fiction**. Alternate History Fiction does not quite fit, as you already recognize.

Oxford American College Dictionary.